# Ajax Post not reaching server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure what is going on. The weird thing is that this used to work and all of a sudden is broken. I don't think it's a break in the jQuery because my unobtrusive validation works great. If I set a break point on my controller I never reach it on button press.

```
<div class="signup-wrapper">
<h3>Register to get updates and contest details</h3>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EmailList", "Account", new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "signup-wrapper",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "Post"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.LabelFor(P => P.FirstName)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.FirstName)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(P => P.LastName)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.LastName)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(P => P.Email)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.Email)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.Email)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(P => P.EmailConfirmation)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.EmailConfirmation)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.EmailConfirmation)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
}
</div>
```

Controller code

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmailList(GarageViewModels.EmailListSignUpViewModel vM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new JDMExchangeEntities())
            {
                context.EmailLists.Add(vM.ReturnModel());
                context.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.IsSignedUp = true;
                return PartialView("EmailSignUpConfirmation");
            }
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Does anyone see anything obvious? I opened up chrome tools to see the requests happen in real time and all I could see happening was the validation jquery making requests but no matter how many times I clicked on the submit I would not see any type of request being sent.

## Update 1

### Adding my jQuery library calls for reference

**Layout.Mobile**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Modded JDM Cars</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/swipe_style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/swipe.js"></script>
```

**Bundle Registration**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

## Update 2 - Troubleshooting Procedure

**Step One**

I checked the networking tab in Google Chrome to see the requests that were being sent to the server and saw that my jQuery validation was working but for some reason when I pressed the submit button I never got a post request to my controller. As per the second comment I intercepted the form submit with some jquery and placed an alert to make sure the post was indeed going through. It definitely was.

**Step Two**

Now that I knew the post was being sent but not received by my controller I thought it might be a coding issue in my viewmodel since ajax requests seem to fail silently if there are errors. Prior to the post request I issued a Get request using remoting to double check for any already existing emails. I added an `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[HttpGet]` attribute to it and tested again.

```
      [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult IsEmailUnique(string Email)
    {
        using (var context = new JDMExchangeEntities())
        {
            var item = context.EmailLists.SingleOrDefault(P => P.Email == Email);

            if (item == null)
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json("Email is already registered.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

It seems that my webapp was failing at this portion of code. After the first Get request would fail the following POST request would too. Now the post works but is being submitted twice so more on that in the next update.

Comment: You can try putting in some jquery to intercept the form submit and check to see that it is being submitted. Something like `$('form').submit(function(){...`

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I added an alert to the function you mentioned and it does pop up when I hit the submit button; however, the Google Chrome network tab is not picking it up at all.

Comment: On chrome do you have the button 'Preserve log on navigation enabled'? It is a grey circle near the top that should turn red when active. Just making sure that the page is not being refreshed and losing the logs.

Comment: Yes it's active. I got part of the problem fixed. Prior to the post to save the user's email I had a remote get request running to check if the email is already registered. That was not getting hit either in debug mode. I added an `[Authorize]` and `[HttpGet]` attribute and that piece of code was able to execute. The post now works as well but for some reason executes twice. I get duplicate records in my db and can see the post issued twice in Fiddler. I will update question to make things a little clearer.

Comment: Not the answer, but I noticed was this line `<div class="signup-wrapper">` should be `<div id="signup-wrapper">` for it to work with `UpdateTargetId = "signup-wrapper"`

Comment: Brent Mannering thanks! That was the next bug on my list to tackle lol. Jeez.. The things you overlook.

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem to the question was solved and written about as an update within the question itself. The last problem dealt with the ajax post being sent twice to the server. It turned out it was the bundles I was using. I think there might have been a duplicate `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` since fiddler showed that piece of javascript as the source of the post. I removed the bundles and simply used

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

instead. This solved the duplicate Post being sent.